# JSP tag - how to limit input to only numbers

Tags: jsp, onkeypress

```
<form:form method="post"     commandName="registerForm" action="${action}">
  <formElement:formSelectBox idKey="register.age"
                             labelKey="register.age" selectCSSClass="form-control"
                             path="titleCode" mandatory="true" skipBlank="false"
                             skipBlankMessageKey="form.select.empty" items="${titles}" />
  <formElement:formInputBox  idKey="register.firstName"
                             labelKey="register.firstName"   
                             path="firstName" inputCSS="form-control"
                             mandatory="true" />
/>
```

I want `age` to only contain numbers and otherwise it should give an error.
But JSP does not have an `onkeypressed` event or `type`.
So, what can I do?

Comment: Do you using **[spring form jsp-tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)** ?  I can not find which view technology you are using